# vs2008 mystery: Quick macro record and playback shortcuts not allowed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In vs2008, Tools, Macros,
**Record TemporaryMacro** keyboard shortcut toggle is Ctrl+Shift+**R**;
**Run TemporaryMacro** keyboard shorcut is Ctrl+Shift+**P** for playback.

I've used them before, but they've stopped working.

If I open Tools, Options, Keyboard, then navigate to a command like
Tools.Run that has no assigned keyboard shortcut, I can experiment
by pretending to assign a keyboard shorcut:  I simply click inside
the "Press shortcut keys:" textbox and try different keystroke
combinations.

Examples:
Ctrl+p:  currently assigned to File.Print
Ctrl+r:  currently assigned to *various* uses
Ctrl+Shift+Q:  available
Ctrl+Shift+B:  currently assigned to Build.BuildSolution
BUT
vs2008 will not even allow me to type either of
Ctrl+Shift+P or Ctrl+Shift+R in the "Press shortcut keys:" textbox.
When I type those combinations, nothing appears in the "Press shortcut keys:" textbox.

Please note:  I can record and playback a temporary macro by
using the menu commands, however, the mouse is like a turtle
when compared to the keyboard.

Any ideas why this very useful vs2008 feature is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snagit 9.1.3 was the culprit.
Snagit is a really useful time saving screen capture tool from Techsmith.

Ctrl+Shift+P ~~ I changed this to **Print Screen**.
Ctrl+Shift+R ~~ repeat last capture is now Ctrl+Shift+Alt+0.

While I was at it, I changed this too:
Ctrl+Shift+X ~~ hide Snagit window toggle is now Ctrl+Shift+Alt+9.

vs2008 has so many keyboard shortcuts predefined that it
is easy for some other software to steal one of them.

g.

P.S.:  Snagit is a commercial product:  http://www.techsmith.com/.

For anyone who needs to frequently capture and annotate screen images,
Snagit will quickly repay its purchase cost in time saved.